# How to obtain the peer IP address in a SSL connection (Qt)

Tags: qt, ssl, ip

In Qt I connect client and host from different LAN via SSL, host IP addresses is 192.168.0.111 and client IP should be 192.168.1.111. I try to use peerAddress() in QSslSocket on the host side to get the client IP, but I seem to get the gateway ip address, i.e. 192.168.0.1, instead of the client's real IP address. What do I miss?

One way to go around is for the client to send its IP address as a message via SSL. In this case, how can I get the ip address of the client PC in my client program (Qt)?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that gateway isn't running some sort of [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)? If it is running NAT, you need to send the client's IP address on the socket yourself. In order to obtain the client's IP address from the client, use [`localAddress()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#localAddress).

Comment: This works. Thank you!